# Wrong resource folder detected for tablets on android

Tags: android, resources, tablet, dimensions

I have a tablet emulator with 1024x600 screen resolution. I would like to create a resource folder for this device. I checked this [table](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) from developer site and this is a "Extra-Large screen with Low density (120dpi), ldpi. I logged these informations from code too and i got this:

```
XLarge sized screen - DENSITY_LOW... Density is 120
```

That's why i created the "values-xlarge-ldpi" folder but the android don't read dimen values from this folder and use the values-sw720dp resources :O  Why? Thank you!

Comment: Using a density qualifier (`-ldpi`) for anything other than drawable resources is a serious code smell, as it is unlikely to give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this part of the doc you linked :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

This is the "new size qualifiers", introduced in Android 3.2. So it's normal that the system use the latest "way" :)

You must use this new way as it's the new one and probablye the most supported in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I tried them too: "dimens-sw600dp-ldpi", "dimens-w1024dp-h600dp" but nothing. So what is the correct name for 1024x600 tablet?